# Break a subfigure set in two lines

Tags: line-breaking, subfloats

Is it possible to break a figure block made by three subfigures in two lines? I would like to maintain the first subfigure on the first line and the other subfigures on the second line.

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
    \subfigure[sub1]{\includegraphics{path1}\label{fig:path1}}
    \subfigure[sub2]{\includegraphics{path2}\label{fig:path2}}
    \subfigure[sub3]{\includegraphics{path3}\label{fig:path3}}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: How are you producing the subfigures? Which package are you using? Anyway, you can use the standard break line command  \\.

Comment: I updated the text and verified that your suggestion works pretty fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is an example that uses the subcaption package and the threeparttable package for the tablenotes environment (environment not strictly necessary, as you could use simple text with \footnotesize)

```
\begin{figure}[t!p]
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
                 \centering
                 \includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{coolcat}
                 \caption{Cool}
                 \label{fig2:coolcat}
         \end{subfigure}
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                 \centering
                 \includegraphics[width=0.985\textwidth]{bossycat}
                 \caption{Bossy}
                 \label{fig2:bossycat}
         \end{subfigure}%
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
                 \centering
                 \includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{frowningcat}
                 \caption{Reflective}
                 \label{fig2:frowningcat}
         \end{subfigure}
% leave a blank line to change row
```

`\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.31\textwidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.985\textwidth]{scaredbabycat}
             \caption{Scared}
             \label{fig2:scared}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.69\textwidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiredcat}
             \caption{Tired}
             \label{fig2:tired}
      \end{subfigure}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item Images in the public domain.
\end{tablenotes}
\caption{Cats} \label{fig2}
\end{figure}`

This produces:

[image]

Comment: @Pierre, it might be useful to list some other packages you might be using. I have not been able to reproduce the result. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for awesome example images :)