# While these multiple subfigures are placed so badly?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have this code where I place 4 plots in two `figure*` blocks:

```
\subsection{Encoders Evaluation}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/mapVLADvsFV.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:mapVLADvsFV}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/timesVLADvsFV.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:timesVLADvsFV}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{VLAD and FV comparison. Figure \ref{fig:mapVLADvsFV} shows precision of the two encoding techniques, while Figure \ref{fig:descTimes} shows their efficiency.}\label{fig:PHA}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/VLADCenters.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:VLADCenters}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/VLADTimes.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:VLADTimes}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{VLAD results depending on the number of centers and descriptors used. Figure \ref{fig:VLADCenters} shows the precision of SURF and PHA, while Figure \ref{fig:descTimes} shows the efficiency of each descriptor..}\label{fig:PHA}
\end{figure*}
```

However, the figures are placed 2 pages later with several other figures... Why this happens?

This is a picture of these plots in the resulting document:

[image]

Comment: If you want thhe pictures to stay together, use a single `figure*` environment. Just replace `\end{figure*}\begin{figure*}` with a blank line.

Comment: And yes, you can have more than one caption per figure.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125294/140011 - see here for a working example solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add option `[t]` to `figure*` environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Encoders Evaluation}
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/mapVLADvsFV.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:mapVLADvsFV}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/timesVLADvsFV.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:timesVLADvsFV}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{VLAD and FV comparison. Figure \ref{fig:mapVLADvsFV} shows precision of the two encoding techniques, while Figure \ref{fig:descTimes} shows their efficiency.}
\label{fig:PHA}
\end{figure*}      % you can omit this and next line
\begin{figure*}[t] % you can omit this line
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/VLADCenters.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:VLADCenters}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/VLADTimes.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:VLADTimes}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{VLAD results depending on the number of centers and descriptors used. Figure \ref{fig:VLADCenters} shows the precision of SURF and PHA, while Figure \ref{fig:descTimes} shows the efficiency of each descriptor..}
\label{fig:PHA}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]